# Why does Required not work on my html input line within my form?

Tags: html, forms, input, message, required

I have added 'required' to my input line for a form I have created in html but when I submit the form without any data it does not show the alert for info is required. Submit button is included within 'form'.

```
 <div class="form-item">
                    <input class="form-item" type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" required>  
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input class="form-item" type="text" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input class="form-item" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                </div>
```

Comment: I believe that you need a form action in order to achieve your intentions

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a form action in your code. If you checkout this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) you can see that W3Schools has one in their code. In the demo, if you take it out, it will not work as intended which is what I suspect is your issue.

Comment: Sorry should have included in my example. I have an action but still not working...   <section id="contact-section">
        <form class="form-box" action="thank-you.html">
            <div class="form-container">

                <div class="form-item">
                    <input class="form-item" type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name"
                        required>
                </div>

Comment: All solved thanks for your help - the button needed to be a submit type!